# What should be the correct way to show div in desktop view and mobile view through media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am new to media query. 
For mobile view and desktop view I am using 2 div, having same thing

One for mobile view and other for desktop view. Both div have same content.

When there is mobile view I hide Desktop view div and vice versa.

My html code is something like this..

```
<div class="mobile">
Welcome to my website<br>
This is mobile view
</div>

<div class="desktop">
Welcome to my website<br>
This is desktop view
</div>
```

And My .css file is something like this

```
.mobile{
    display: none;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .mobile{
        display: block;
    }
    .desktop{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Is this technique OK?

Any other suggestions for doing the same?

Comment: This is not recommended.In your case use only one div element.Change the css of the div element depending upon how you want to see in mobile or in desktop using media query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to simply apply new styles to one DIV which is used through all screen sizes. This means there is less redundant HTML.

With your approach, you could go down the route of creating two HTML structures one for mobile and one for desktop. This really isn't necessary. The same results can be achieved by applying new styles to the same DIVS to adapt to different screen sizes.

For example, if you have a div containing a paragraph and you want to change the text colour to orange when on a small device.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
div p{
   color: orange;
}

}
```

What I do is then have another CSS file usually named 'custom.css' to include all your general styles that will be applied outside of any media queries.

Try to contain most of your styling in a general style sheet and then make minor and minimal changes to styles using media queries.

I also typically have a "media.css" separate style sheet. I prefer it, seems more organised in my head.

My CSS folder normally consists of the following style sheets:

custom.css <-- Containing general styles - this is the base for all styles. I always try to cover

media.css <-- containing media queries for different screen sizes and device orientations. Use this to make small changes (little tweaks for each device)

You may also want a styles.css to just normalise some styles that are already set. Or, you could just include this as part of your custom.css fiile

Edit: I'm new to answering on stack overflow. Hopefully, this makes sense to you, ill try to answer any other questions if you need.